# How to plot a vector field in Julia?

Tags: plot, julia, plotly, plotly.js

I want to plot a vector field in Julia. I could not find an example [here](http://docs.juliaplots.org/latest/examples/pyplot/).
[Here](https://gist.github.com/gizmaa/7214002#streamplot) there are some examples using `plotly`, however, they do not work for me. I would like to plot the vector field by `plotlyjs` or `plotly`.

Here is an example code in Julia:

```
using Plots
pyplot()
x = collect(linspace(0,10,100));
X = repmat(x,1,length(x));
Y = repmat(x',length(x),1);
U = cos.(X.*Y);
V = sin.(X.*Y);
streamplot(X,Y,U,V)
```

Here is the Matlab example:

```
[x,y] = meshgrid(0:0.2:2,0:0.2:2);
u = cos(x).*y;
v = sin(x).*y;

figure
quiver(x,y,u,v)
```

[image]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The short answer: use `quiver` from Plots.jl.

```
quiver(x, y, quiver=(u, v))
```

---

In the following, I'll attempt to fully recreate the example you showed in Matlab.

First, we'll import `Plots` and enable the `plotly` backend.

```
using Plots
plotly()
```

We need to define a function similar to Matlab's `meshgrid`. Since Plots will operate on our arrays of points regardless of their dimensionality, I chose to simply use `repeat` and use the "flattened" outputs.

```
 meshgrid(x, y) = (repeat(x, outer=length(y)), repeat(y, inner=length(x)))
```

Now, we can create `x`, `y`, `u`, and `v` using the same logic as the Matlab code. For the sake of brevity, we can use the `@.` macro to vectorize all calls in the given expression.

```
x, y = meshgrid(0:0.2:2, 0:0.2:2)
u = @. cos(x) * y
v = @. sin(x) * y
```

From here, we can simply use the `quiver` function from Plots, passing `u` and `v` as a 2-tuple to the keyword argument `quiver`.

```
quiver(x, y, quiver=(u, v))
```

[image: Initial plot]

The result is close to the Matlab output, but it seems that Plots.jl scales the arrows to be longer than they are in Matlab. This is easily fixable, though; we can simply broadcast-multiply `u` and `v` by a scale constant.

```
scale = 0.2
u = @. scale * cos(x) * y
v = @. scale * sin(x) * y
```

[image: Final plot]

Comment: Thanks! Is there any link to the documentation of `Plots.jl`, which explains `quiver`?

Comment: @MOON The `quiver` keyword argument is documented as a series attribute in [this table](http://docs.juliaplots.org/latest/attributes/#series). However, it looks like the documentation [isn't there yet](https://github.com/JuliaPlots/Plots.jl/issues/466) for the `quiver` function itself.