# How can I plot vector field on Julia?

Tags: plot, julia

I'm new on Julia and I've tried to make the code of following post [How to plot a vector field in Julia?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51466537/how-to-plot-a-vector-field-in-julia), but, didn't work, so, I would like to know if it's possible to plot with the package "Plots" and how? It'll be very important to my research.

P.s.: Someone gave to me the following code, but, actually, I don't know why isn't working:

```
using Plots
gr(size=(600,400))

function example()
  X = linspace(-2, 2, 100)
  Y = linspace(-2, 2, 100)
  f(x, y) = x^3 - 3x + y^2
  contour(X, Y, f)

  x = linspace(-2, 2, 11)
  y = linspace(-2, 2, 11)
  df(x, y) = [3x^2 - 3; 2y] / 25
  quiver!(x, y', quiver=df, c=:blue)

  xlims!(-2, 2)
  ylims!(-2, 2)
  png("example")
end

example()
```

Comment: Does this [previous SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51466537) help?

Comment: BTW, it's helpful if you elaborate "isn't working" more.  For example, there are error messages (and show them), the plot doesn't look right, there is no plot, etc.

Comment: We need more information. For example, if you are on Julia 1.0 you will get errors because `linspace` doesn't exist anymore (one should use `range` from now on) which is completely unrelated to plotting.

Answer (score 12):

As has already been said in the comments, you should provide error messages as well as people otherwise have to guess what's wrong with your code.

However, in your case I think I could guess it :)

On Julia 1.0 the following works:

```
using Plots
gr(size=(600,400))

function example()
  X = range(-2, stop=2, length=100)
  Y = range(-2, stop=2, length=100)
  f(x, y) = x^3 - 3x + y^2
  contour(X, Y, f)

  x = range(-2, stop=2, length=11)
  y = range(-2, stop=2, length=11)
  df(x, y) = [3x^2 - 3; 2y] / 25
  quiver!(x, y', quiver=df, c=:blue)

  xlims!(-2, 2)
  ylims!(-2, 2)
  png("example")
end

example()
```

and gives the following output

[image]

Note that I only changed all occurences of `linspace` to `range(-2, stop=2, length=X)` because the linspace function [has been deprecated](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/pull/25896) in Julia 0.7.

Comment: Thanks for this great answer! I've been trying to reproduce your example (in order to optimize my own vectorfield plotting functions), but it's not working on Julia 1.5.3 (`quiver()` expects `y` each column to contain 11 rows). I'm not sure what developments Julia has undergone between when you answered and now--does Plots no longer broadcast the input data as it did when you posted this? I'd love to get your elegant solution to work again. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

For Plots v1.10.4, you need to provide a start position for every quiver

```
# same code as in above answer
quiver!(repeat(x,11), vec(repeat(y',11)), quiver=df, c=:blue)
```

Answer (score 3):

Updating the answer to Julia 1.6.3,

Helper function source: [How to plot a vector field in Julia?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51466537/how-to-plot-a-vector-field-in-julia)

```
using Plots
gr(size=(600,400))

meshgrid(x, y) = (repeat(x, outer=length(y)), repeat(y, inner=length(x))) # helper function to create a quiver grid.

function example()
  X = range(-2, stop=2, length=100)
  Y = range(-2, stop=2, length=100)
  f(x, y) = x^3 - 3x + y^2
  Plots.contour(X, Y, f)

  xs,ys = meshgrid(range(-2, stop=2, length=11), range(-2,stop=2,length=11))
  df(x, y) = [3x^2 - 3; 2y] / 25
  quiver!(xs, ys, quiver=df, c=:blue)

  xlims!(-2, 2)
  ylims!(-2, 2)
  png("example")
end

example()
```

[image]